# "Error: not found: java" when running webdriver.io test

Tags: java, node.js, selenium, visual-studio-code, webdriver-io

I'm trying to run a [webdriver.io test suite](https://github.com/DEFRA/rod-licensing-tests/tree/master/packages/frontend-acceptance-tests) from the VS Code debugger but it is failing with the error message:

```
ERROR @wdio/cli:utils: A service failed in the 'onPrepare' hook
Error: not found: java
at getNotFoundError (/Users/andrew/projects/rod-licensing-tests/packages/frontend-acceptance-tests/node_modules/selenium-standalone/node_modules/which/which.js:10:17)
```

How do I get round this? From looking at similar issues on the web, I've tried the following with the same results:

1. `npm install`
2. installing Java using `npm install java`
3. installing selenium-standalone with `./node_modules/.bin/selenium-standalone install`
4. adding an environment variable to my `launch.json` config: `"JAVA_HOME": "/usr/libexec/java_home"`
5. updating Java on my Mac to Java 8 update 271 via System Preferences

The tests do run successfully using Docker, but I'd ideally want to run this from the IDE too so that I can quickly start and debug them. Also, my colleague can run the same tests using config in IntelliJ IDE Ultimate but I feel this should be possible in VS Code too.

This is the current content of my `launch.json` file:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Launch via NPM",
      "type": "pwa-node",
      "args": [
        "conf/local.conf.js",
        "--logLevel trace"
      ],
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/packages/frontend-acceptance-tests",
      "env": {
        "JAVA_HOME": "/usr/libexec/java_home",
        "SERVICE_URL": "[redacted]",
        "OAUTH_AUTHORITY_HOST_URL": "[redacted]",
        "OAUTH_TENANT": "[redacted]",
        "OAUTH_CLIENT_ID": "[redacted]",
        "OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET": "[redacted]",
        "OAUTH_SCOPE": "[redacted]",
        "DYNAMICS_API_PATH": "[redacted]",
        "DYNAMICS_API_VERSION": "9.1"
      },
      "request": "launch",
      "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}/packages/frontend-acceptance-tests/node_modules/.bin/wdio",
      "runtimeVersion": "14.13.0"
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm pretty new to Node.JS so still learning how it fits together. Any suggestions appreciated!

Comment: As you are using 'selenium-standalone' you will need JAVA-JDK  installed on your machine https://webdriver.io/docs/selenium-standalone-service.html . In current project package.json already contains selenium-standalone dependency so it should be available to  you. Refer this https://webdriver.io/docs/debugging.html for launch.json

Comment: Thanks Rahul. I've changed my launch.json to be closer to the webdriver.io debugging document and the original java error has now disappeared! I now get this:
`ERROR @wdio/runner: /Users/andrew/projects/rod-licensing-tests/packages/frontend-acceptance-tests/node_modules/simple-oauth2/lib/client.js:19
  #config = null` so will investigate further.

Comment: @RahulL Now fixed thanks to your wdio debugging link! I think the key was: set `"type": "node"`, remove `"runtimeExecutable"` and add `"program": "${workspaceFolder}/packages/frontend-acceptance-tests/node_modules/.bin/wdio"`. Feel free to respond as a full answer and I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case we are using selenium-standalone-service for running the test then JAVA-JDK need to be installed. Also below dependency should be available in the package.json

```
{
    "devDependencies": {
        "@wdio/selenium-standalone-service": "^6.6.1"
    }
}
```

or

```
>npm install @wdio/selenium-standalone-service --save-dev
```

**For VScode debugging**

As per [documentation](https://webdriver.io/docs/debugging.html) we will need [JavaScript Debugger (Nightly)](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.js-debug-nightly) enabled.

Sample .vscode/launch.json should looks like

```
{
    "name": "run select spec",
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "args": ["wdio.conf.js", "--spec", "${file}"],
    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
    "autoAttachChildProcesses": true,
    "program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/@wdio/cli/bin/wdio.js",
    "console": "integratedTerminal"
},
```

Example : [launch.json](https://github.com/mgrybyk/webdriverio-devtools/blob/master/.vscode/launch.json)

Comment: This fixed it for me. The key bit for me was that my `launch.json` was incorrect but the documentation link pointed me in the right direction. I'm on a Mac so it looks like Nightly is not needed for me. Thanks Rahul!

Answer (score 1):

You usually need to configure your project sdk with Java version 1.8 which can be installed from this link:

https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase-jdk8-downloads.html

But I see you already tried that. Perhaps you need to add the selenium jar files to your project's dependencies.

Comment: That helps and I've checked my installation of JDK8. Trying to add the dependency still gave me a similar issue but from Rahul's suggestion in the comments, it looks like dependency is already set and the issue might be how I've set up WDIO in VS Code. I'll carry on down that route - thanks for your help!

Comment: I see, no worries! Good luck (: